# c# serializing complex types using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am new to C# in general and a newbie using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert, JsonConverter. I need to serialize a complex type which has the definition as follows:

```
public class UserDetails
{
        public string _name;
        public Dictionary<string, List<TaskDetails>> _userSchedule;
}

public class TaskDetails
{
        public string _taskDescription;
        public DateTime _deadLine;

}
```

When I try to serialize UserDetails, the serialized string does not have all details. My unit test is as follows:

```
UserDetails obj = new UserDetails("abc");
Dictionary<string, List<TaskDetails>> _schedules = new Dictionary<string,List<TaskDetails>>();

List<TaskDetails> _sched1 = new List<TaskDetails>();
_sched1.Add(new TaskDetails("pickup", new DateTime(2014, 04, 10)));
_sched1.Add(new TaskDetails("store", new DateTime(2014, 04, 15)));

List<TaskDetails> _sched2 = new List<TaskDetails>();
_sched2.Add(new TaskDetails("write doc", new DateTime(2014, 04, 15)));

_schedules.Add("external activity", _sched1);
_schedules.Add("internal", _sched2);
```

During serialization,

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;

I see that doing the one below is not enough. It serializes the dictionary but the custom Type within the 'List' is ignored. And I need to use JsonConverter, but not sure how to do that. 

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_schedules, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Can you please provide some pointers?

Regards
Jay

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored"?  What JSON are you expecting, and what JSON are you getting instead?  Also, why do you think you need a JsonConverter here?  I don't see anything here that would require it.

Comment: You are right, I can see the correct serialized output; was comparing it incorrectly.Thanks